# Selenium IDE 3.17, defining nested variable

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to visit list of links and download something from each of them. At the stage where i am at, i couldn't achieve to read links from out csv file. So i decide to store all links as a variable and i write loop to visit each of them at a time. I will name these variables with consecutive numbers like "1,2,3,4,...,6500", and then i will call each at a time. What i am asking is about that. My nested variables didn't work. Here is my code that not worked:
[image]

I also tried `open|retuned ${${s}}|` to get link but it returns "unexpected token '{'",error.

In an nutshell, i need to visit my stored links each at a time, but i couldn't call my links. how can i achive this?

p.s.I know its not useful to store thousands of links, If there is any advice about alternatives, if wish to listen.

Comment: I also have this problem...

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array with the links, then add a “for each” loop to iterate through the array and open up each link.

Here’s some example code:

[image]

Let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i found this recommend online and tried it later i asked here. but i think because of my links lenght and count (over 150 character and 50 links), after first iteration selenium couldn't call 2. item in array. a circle was turning near that code, i waited hours but not worked. i changed my approach, with my new code i can dowload what i need easier than that. but arrays or nested variable thing not worked.

Comment: All right. Good to hear you were able to make it work in the end, cheers!